# Variable scope in case of an exception in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

```
while True:
  try:
    2/0
  except Exception as e:
    break

print e
```

Gives: integer division or modulo by zero

I thought scope of `e` is within the `while` block and it will not be accessible in the outside `print` statement. What did I miss ?

Comment: Of course, you should only use e within the except, simply because it doesn't exist (or is something different) if you never hit the exception.

Comment: @KennyOstrom good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple: `while` does not create a scope in Python. Python has only the following scopes:

- function scope (may include closure variables)
- class scope (only while the class is being defined)
- global (module) scope
- comprehension/generator expression scope

So when you leave the `while` loop, `e`, being a local variable (if the loop is in a function) or a global variable (if not), is still available.

tl;dr: Python is not C.

Comment: Can you also look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906375/multithreaded-file-read-python

Comment: On a side note, in Python 3, `e` is deleted before exiting the `except` clause: https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except

Comment: But you can save its value to another variable in the `except` clause: "This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be able to refer to it after the except clause."

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across something similar.  The `as` in the except does not behave as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

exc = 'foofoo'
print('exc in locals?', 'exc' in locals())
try:
  x = 1 / 0
except Exception as exc:
  print('exc in locals?', 'exc' in locals())
  print('Error', exc)
print('exc in locals?', 'exc' in locals())
print('Sorry, got an exception', exc)
```

This results in the following output.  `NameError` is indicates that `exc` is no longer in `locals()`.

```
% ./g.py 
exc in locals? True
exc in locals? True
Error division by zero
exc in locals? False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./g.py", line 11, in <module>
    print('Sorry, got an exception', exc)
NameError: name 'exc' is not defined
%
```

The `as ex` removed the the variable from the scope.  I have not been found the explanation for this.  This code produces the expected output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

exc = 'foofoo'
print('exc in locals?', 'exc' in locals())
try:
  x = 1 / 0
except Exception as exc_:
  exc = str(exc_)
  print('exc in locals?', 'exc' in locals())
  print('Error, exc)
print('exc in locals?', 'exc' in locals())
print('Sorry, got an exception', exc)
```

This explains the observed behavior:[Python 3 try statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

Answer (score 2):

in `except ... as e`, the `e` will be drop when Jump out of `try except`, Whether or not it was defined before.

> When an exception has been assigned using as target, it is cleared at the end of the except clause.

refer to offical website link:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Comment: The question was originally tagged `python-2.x`, and the behaviour you describe is 3.x-specific.

Comment: OH，I ignored the tag `python-2.x`, I was careless。