# What is the scope of the `as` binding in an `except` statement or context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I know that in general python only makes new scopes for classes, functions etc., but I'm confused by the `as` statement in a try/except block or context manager. Variables assigned inside the block are accessible outside it, which makes sense, but the variable bound with `as` itself is not.

So this fails:

```
try:
    raise RuntimeError()
except RuntimeError as error:
    pass

print(repr(error))
```

but this succeeds:

```
try:
    raise RuntimeError()
except RuntimeError as e:
    error = e

print(repr(error))
```

What's going on with the variable bound with `as`, and why don't normal python scoping rules apply? The [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement) indicates that it's just a normally bound python variable, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Normal scope rules do apply, but there is an additional "unbind" operation performed by the `except` clause when it completes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in [PEP 3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#semantic-changes), as well as [current documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), variables bound with `as` in an `except` block are explicitly and specially cleared at the end of the block, even though they share the same local scope. This improves the immediacy of garbage collection. The `as` syntax was originally not available for exceptions in 2.x; it was backported [for 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), but the old semantics [were preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923315/variable-scope-in-case-of-an-exception-in-python).

The same **does not apply** to `with` blocks:

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager
>>> @contextmanager
... def test():
...     yield
... 
>>> with test() as a:
...     pass
... 
>>> a # contains None; does not raise NameError
>>> 
>>> def func(): # similarly within a function
...     with test() as a:
...         pass
...     return a
... 
>>> func()
>>>
```

The behaviour is specific to the `except` block, *not* to the `as` keyword.

Comment: @wjandrea I had internalized a rule to suppress syntax highlighting for REPL sessions, because they aren't proper code; but I see the highlighting works just fine. Having the `>>>` and `...` in "keyword" colour looks perfectly acceptable, yeah.

Comment: Yeah, you might have learned that before SE switched to highlight.js. The new `lang-python` syntax handles prompts just fine, although [we still don't have support for the full `lang-python-repl`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355221/343832).

Comment: Would btw be more usable without all those `...`, then someone wanting to try this wouldn't have to remove them. Python 3.10 IDLE does that.

Comment: The code here isn't meant to be used; it's just demonstrating my claim. Code without the `...` would either appear misindented due to the `>>>`, or be awkwardly indented after copying and pasting. Removing the first four characters of each line in a block is easy with some text editors, including the one I use.

Answer (score 6):

This is a documented exception to the normal rules that *specifically applies to `try-except` statements, from the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When an exception has been assigned using as target, it is cleared at
> the end of the except clause. This is as if:
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     foo
> ```
>
> was translated to
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     try:
>         foo
>     finally:
>         del N
> ```
>
> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be
> able to refer to it after the except clause. Exceptions are cleared
> because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference
> cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive
> until the next garbage collection occurs.

As noted, the reason this occurs to prevent reference cycles.

Note, this *only* applies to a `try - except` compound statement, `as` is not an independent statement, it is a part of different, independent compound statements (`with` and `try-except`)